# mysqldump package is not exporting stored procedure and stored functions

Tags: stored-procedures, mysqldumpslow

When I execute mysqldump to command line then it works and exports the complete database along with all tables and stored procedures and stored functions. But when I use npm mysqldump in nodejs then they are only exports tables but not stored procedure and stored functions. I got stuck

```
await mysqldump({
      connection: {
        host: process.env.HOST,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
      },
      dumpToFile: backupFilePath,
      additional: ['--routines'],
    });
```